# get request in perl and Use of uninitialized value

Tags: perl

```
my $url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=journal+of+medical+virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]&usehistory=y";
  print "\n before url \n";
  print $url;
  #post the esearch URL
  my $output = get($url);
  print $output;
```

I have not used perl ever before.

If I hit this URL in browser, I do get the XML.
However, From what I see in output from script, `$output` is empty and

```
print $output;
```

returns

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./extractEmails.pl line 48.
```

Please suggest what's wrong and how to fix it

Edit:

As suggested, complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# A perlscript written by Joseph Hughes, University of Glasgow
# use this perl script to parse the email addressed from the affiliations in PubMed

use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

my ($query,@queries);
#Query the Journal of Virology from 2014 until the present (use 3000)
$query = 'journal+of+virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Journal of General Virology
$query = 'journal+of+general+virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Virology
$query = 'virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Archives of Virology
$query = 'archives+of+virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Virus Research
$query = 'virus+research[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Antiviral Research
$query = 'antiviral+research[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Viruses
$query = 'viruses[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Journal of Medical Virology
$query = 'journal+of+medical+virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';

# global variables
push(@queries,$query);
my %emails;
my $emailcnt=0;
my $count=1;
#assemble the esearch URL
foreach my $query (@queries){
  my $base = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/';
  #my $url = $base . "esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=$query&usehistory=y";
  my $url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=journal+of+medical+virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]&usehistory=y";
  print "\n before url \n";
  print $url;
  #post the esearch URL
  my $output = get($url);
  print "\n before output \n";
  print get($url);
  print $output;
  #parse WebEnv, QueryKey and Count (# records retrieved)
  my $web = $1 if ($output =~ /<WebEnv>(\S+)<\/WebEnv>/);
  my $key = $1 if ($output =~ /<QueryKey>(\d+)<\/QueryKey>/);
  my $count = $1 if ($output =~ /<Count>(\d+)<\/Count>/);

  #retrieve data in batches of 500
  my $retmax = 500;
  for (my $retstart = 0; $retstart < $count; $retstart += $retmax) {
    my $efetch_url = $base ."efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&WebEnv=$web";
    $efetch_url .= "&query_key=$key&retmode=xml";
    my $efetch_out = get($efetch_url);
    my @matches = $efetch_out =~ m(<Affiliation>(.*)</Affiliation>)g;
    #print "$_\n" for @matches;
    for my $match (@matches){
      if ($match=~/\s([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]+)$/){
        my $email=$1;
        $email=~s/\.$//;
        $emails{$email}++;
      }     
    }
  }
  my $cnt= keys %emails;
  print "$query\n$cnt\n";
}

print "Total number of emails: ";
my $cnt= keys %emails;
print "$cnt\n";
my @email = keys %emails;
my @VAR;
push @VAR, [ splice @email, 0, 100 ] while @email;

my $batch=100;
foreach my $VAR (@VAR){
    open(OUT, ">Set_$batch\.txt") || die "Can't open file!\n";
    print OUT join(",",@$VAR);
    close OUT;
    $batch=$batch+100;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. I have no idea what that `get` sub does.

Comment: @Robert Updated with entire code snippet

Comment: I didn't ask for the complete code, I asked for a *minimal* example that shows the problem.

Comment: @Robert: I got the code from https://gist.github.com/josephhughes/8e5d32dcd808a51c008f . As I mentioned I have not used perl before, I safely assumed get was a perl provided native function. Only use statements that I have so far in the script are :use strict;
use LWP::Simple;" as in the snipped shared

Comment: @GMB...........Please check my last comment

Comment: I just googled and found get is coming from use LWP::Simple;

Comment: note that the most common underlying problem is no https support, which can be fixed by installing LWP::Protocol::https and its dependencies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend against using LWP::Simple for any reason because it is impossible to configure it or handle errors usefully. Using [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) which it wraps is nearly as simple anyway (though the error handling is a bit complicated). The below examples would replace the `use LWP::Simple;` and `my $output = get($url);` lines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 30);
my $response = $ua->get($url);
unless ($response->is_success) {
  # the Client-Warning, Client-Aborted, and X-Died headers each may be set on client/transport errors
  die $response->status_line;
}
my $output = $response->decoded_content;
```

The core [HTTP::Tiny](https://perldoc.pl/HTTP::Tiny) is also simple.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Tiny;
my $ua = HTTP::Tiny->new;
my $response = $ua->get($url);
unless ($response->{success}) {
  die $response->{status} == 599 ? $response->{content} : "$response->{status} $response->{reason}";
}
my $output = $response->{content};
```

If you really want an LWP::Simple approach that will at least report transport errors, try [ojo](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo) from Mojolicious:

```
perl -Mojo -E'say g(shift)->text' http://example.com
```

In a script rather than a oneliner, you can use [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) directly, and also handle HTTP errors like above:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get($url)->result;
unless ($response->is_success) {
  die $response->code . ' ' . $response->message;
}
my $output = $response->text;
```

Comment: You changed the words, but it still says the same wrong thing. Again, there is no issue preventing the handling of errors. All one needs is `unless (defined($got))` instead of `unless ($response->is_success)`. The problem is only the lack of information about what error occurred.

Comment: "I recommend against using LWP::Simple for any reason because it is impossible to configure it, and because it doesn't provide useful error messages. LWP::Simple is simply a wrapper for LWP::UserAgent, which is really just as simple to use directly anyway."

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `-E` in code you recommend because `-E` isn't forward-compatible. You can use `CORE::say` without `-E`.

Comment: Thanks but I am getting "500 Can't verify SSL peers without knowing which Certificate Authorities to trust at line 56"

Comment: I did   $ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostname => 0 );
to fix it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Simran kaur, That's like getting a nice alarm system, but never turning it on. Don't trust strangers on the internet; adjust who you trust (e.g. using Mozilla::CA?).