# perl script to parse data from pubmed not returning data

Tags: perl

I am very new to perl and this is my first time using any perl script. I have a script to parse emailIDs from pubmed

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# A perlscript written by Joseph Hughes, University of Glasgow
# use this perl script to parse the email addressed from the affiliations in PubMed

use strict;
#use LWP::Simple;
use LWP::Protocol::https;
use LWP::UserAgent;


my ($query,@queries);
#Query the Journal of Virology from 2014 until the present (use 3000)
$query = 'journal+of+virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Journal of General Virology
$query = 'journal+of+general+virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Virology
$query = 'virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Archives of Virology
$query = 'archives+of+virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Virus Research
$query = 'virus+research[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Antiviral Research
$query = 'antiviral+research[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Viruses
$query = 'viruses[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';
push(@queries,$query);
#Journal of Medical Virology
$query = 'journal+of+medical+virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]';

# global variables
push(@queries,$query);
my %emails;
my $emailcnt=0;
my $count=1;
#assemble the esearch URL
foreach my $query (@queries){
  my $base = 'http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/';
  my $url = $base . "esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=$query&usehistory=y";
  #my $url = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=journal+of+medical+virology[journal]+AND+2014[Date+-+Publication]:3000[Date+-+Publication]&usehistory=y";
  print "\n before url \n";
  print $url;
  #post the esearch URL
  #my $output = get($url);
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 30);
  $ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostname => 0 );
  my $response = $ua->get($url);
  print "before response";
  print $response;
  unless ($response->is_success) {
  # the Client-Warning, Client-Aborted, and X-Died headers each may be set on client/transport errors
  die $response->status_line;
  }
my $output = $response->decoded_content;
  print "\n before output \n";
  print $output;
  #parse WebEnv, QueryKey and Count (# records retrieved)
  my $web = $1 if ($output =~ /<WebEnv>(\S+)<\/WebEnv>/);
  my $key = $1 if ($output =~ /<QueryKey>(\d+)<\/QueryKey>/);
  my $count = $1 if ($output =~ /<Count>(\d+)<\/Count>/);

  #retrieve data in batches of 500
  my $retmax = 500;
  for (my $retstart = 0; $retstart < $count; $retstart += $retmax) {
    my $efetch_url = $base ."efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&WebEnv=$web";
    $efetch_url .= "&query_key=$key&retmode=xml";
    my $efetch_out = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 30)->get($efetch_url);
    my @matches = $efetch_out =~ m(<Affiliation>(.*)</Affiliation>)g;
    #print "$_\n" for @matches;
    for my $match (@matches){
      if ($match=~/\s([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]+)$/){
        my $email=$1;
        $email=~s/\.$//;
        $emails{$email}++;
      }     
    }
  }
  my $cnt= keys %emails;
  print "$query\n$cnt\n";
}

print "Total number of emails: ";
my $cnt= keys %emails;
print "$cnt\n";
my @email = keys %emails;
my @VAR;
push @VAR, [ splice @email, 0, 100 ] while @email;

my $batch=100;
foreach my $VAR (@VAR){
    open(OUT, ">Set_$batch\.txt") || die "Can't open file!\n";
    print OUT join(",",@$VAR);
    close OUT;
    $batch=$batch+100;
}
```

This is running fine but after running it, I am getting `Total number of emails: 0` which I am pretty sure is not actually the case.

Do we know what is going on here? I can see results like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE eSearchResult PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD esearch 20060628//EN" "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20060628/esearch.dtd">
<eSearchResult><Count>1552</Count><RetMax>20</RetMax><RetStart>0</RetStart><QueryKey>1</QueryKey><WebEnv>NCID_1_108762718_130.14.18.34_9001_1545718459_2017377343_0MetA0_S_MegaStore</WebEnv><IdList>
<Id>30578684</Id>
<Id>30578670</Id>
<Id>30575982</Id>
<Id>30570784</Id>
<Id>30570771</Id>
<Id>30570770</Id>
<Id>30570759</Id>
<Id>30570750</Id>
<Id>30560545</Id>
<Id>30552705</Id>
<Id>30549048</Id>
<Id>30548936</Id>
<Id>30548642</Id>
<Id>30537228</Id>
<Id>30537157</Id>
<Id>30516836</Id>
<Id>30515847</Id>
<Id>30512182</Id>
<Id>30512180</Id>
<Id>30489644</Id>
```

after the get request has run

Source of script: [Script link on github](https://gist.github.com/josephhughes/8e5d32dcd808a51c008f)

Comment: Please [edit] your post and reduce the program to something smaller. Leave in only one of the queries that is failing, and try to find out _where_ exactly your program goes off the rails. Most likely you can `print` the progress in strategic locations to see where your program is. Maybe it just doesn't find any email in the results? Have you inspected what is in `my $efetch_out = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 30)->get($efetch_url);` ? It certainly isn't a string containing the web page.

Comment: Also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916945/get-request-in-perl-and-use-of-uninitialized-value , which you also posted and which has a reply with working code.

Comment: Not answering your question, but your inner for loop does not change the url from iteration to iteration.

Comment: $web is a variable in the url, so the url should change. I would suggest running perlcritic ( level 5 at least ) on this script to detect some issues, then refactoring some functionality into methods to make it readable. This could be written much nicer using objects, but functions would already help

Answer (score 0):

This script could do with some refactoring, so one can actually debug and maintain it.

Probably using an object oriented approach would help greatly,
for me, regexing the `@queries` declaration into a proper list declaration, and clearing out some cruft, renaming variables to what they actually do instead of commenting ( retmax -> batch_size ? ) seem like obvious low hanging fruit.

Handling errors would be next on my list ( what happens if there are no query parameters found? The script continues despite a count of 0 / none found, such behavior is confusing when debugging )

I have not done this for you, and I am also not sure whether a web scraper for emails is actually a great thing to have, but that aside:

If you change the line you commented out `#print "$_\n" for @matches;` to `print "no emails found for query '$query'\n" unless @matches;` you will see clearly why the script does not do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Without running the code myself, I would speculate that the `@matches` array in the code is empty. Try un-commenting the print statement to verify whether or not `@match` is being assigned as expected, and work backward or forward from there to narrow down which statement(s) are not doing what they are expected to.

```
my @matches = $efetch_out =~ m(<Affiliation>(.*)</Affiliation>)g;
#print "$_\n" for @matches;
```

That being said, ideally this code should be completely rewritten in a less procedural style for maintainability.